# How to get the latest offset from the Kafka topic in Confluent kafka C# library?

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am using Confluent kafka C# client. how to get the latest offset consumed from a topic in this?

Answer (score 7):

In addition to previous answer, you can use

```
List<TopicPartitionOffsetError> Position(IEnumerable<TopicPartition> partitions)
```

It will return the last offset polled from librdkafka for given topic/partitions

You have a similar `Committed` method, for the latest committed offset from consumer

---

Also you can query the latest known offsets

```
WatermarkOffsets QueryWatermarkOffsets(TopicPartition topicPartition, TimeSpan timeout)
```

it will send a request to kafka cluster. The call is blocking, set a proper timeout. Currently, you cannot send a request on multiple partition at once.
You can use it either to get last known offset, either to compute lag

There is also

```
WatermarkOffsets GetWatermarkOffsets(TopicPartition topicPartition)
```

which will query the internal state in librdkafka, and could return INVALID_OFFSET (-1001). You can use it to detect some lag due to processing the data. (difference between position and result of this method)

Answer (score 1):

When you receive a message it should include the topic, partition, and offset from where it came (in addition to the Key and Value).

From the [example here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/examples/AdvancedConsumer/Program.cs):

```
consumer.OnMessage += (_, msg)
  => Console.WriteLine($"Topic: {msg.Topic} Partition: {msg.Partition} " +
        $"Offset: {msg.Offset} {msg.Value}");
```

You also get an event when it reaches the end of the each topic partition

```
consumer.OnPartitionEOF += (_, end)
  => Console.WriteLine($"Reached end of topic {end.Topic} partition {end.Partition}" +
          $" , next message will be at offset {end.Offset}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of retrieving offset information from consumer (I didn't want to consume message first) I was able to read topic offsets (`high` and `low`) from producer like this:

```
var partitionOffset = _producer.QueryWatermarkOffsets(new TopicPartition("myTopic", myPartition), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Position()` method from the consumer
like:

```
var partition = 0;
Offset lastOffset = _kafkaConsumer.Position(new TopicPartition("topic", partition));
```